# Multiplying two variables (JS) displaying on input

Tags: javascript

i have an exercise where i need to display items, prices, price by quantity, etc... i am having difficulty multiplying the price by the quantity. below is my code with the inputs and options i am displaying, and the script functions below, help will be very much appreciated!:

```
<body>
<label>Choose Item</label>
<select onChange="getPrice(this)">
  <option></option>
  <option>Tomatoes</option>
  <option>Lettuce</option>
  <option>Potato</option>
  <option>Carrots</option>
  <option>Artichoke</option>
</select>
<br/>
<label>Price</label>
  <input type="text" id="price" />
<br/>
<label>Quantity</label>
<select onChange="getFull(this)">
  <option></option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
<br />
<label>Total $</label>
  <input type="text" id="quantityPrice" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  var veggy = {};
  veggy ["Tomatoes"] = 5.99 
  veggy ["Lettuce"] = 7.66 
  veggy ["Potato"] = 4.52 
  veggy ["Carrots"] = 2.13 
  veggy ["Artichoke"] = 10.58

function getPrice(select) {
    document.getElementById("price").value = veggy[select.value];
}

var quantity = {};
  quantity ["1"] = 1 
  quantity ["2"] = 2
  quantity ["3"] = 3
  quantity ["4"] = 4
  quantity ["5"] = 5

function getFull(select) {
    document.getElementById("quantityPrice").value = (quantity[select.value] * veggy [select.value]);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've added an answer, try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is because you are trying to get values from `veggy` object with keys of `price` select.

```
function getFull(select) {
    document.getElementById("quantityPrice").value = (quantity[select.value] * veggy [select.value]);
}
```

Here you are passing the reference of `quanntity` select, but you have to get the `price` form `Item` object.

Just give an `Id` to your first `select` for ChooseItems.

```
<select id="veggy" onChange="getPrice(this)">
```

And `getFull` like this

```
function getFull(select) {
    var vegSelect = document.getElementById('veggy');
    document.getElementById("quantityPrice").value = (quantity[select.value] * (veggy[vegSelect.value]));
}
```

Comment: it works! thank you very much! not sure i understand why you added the var veg select though....

Comment: @Yaelix I am getting Items select box to get selected value of that

Answer (score 0):

convert the number to string in value..

```
document.getElementById("quantityPrice").value =''+ (quantity[select.value] * veggy [select.value]);
```